# Can You Protect Yourself From Spores With A Bandana?

Tags: biology, post-apocalypse, zombies

Currently I'm working on a project where there's a zombie plague going on that's transmitted through spores (for reference, it's basically like the infection from The Last of Us). I was wondering if something as basic as a bandanna would be able to prevent the spores from getting into your lungs, or if you would need something like a dust mask or a gas mask to fully protect yourself.

Send help, the zombies are here now...

Comment: Pollen grains are spores. Does the bandana stop pollen grains? (That is to say, can it protect you from hay fever?) If yes, then it's fine. (Unless the spores are bacterial spores. Those are much smaller than pollen grains. So the question is, what kind of spores are we talking about?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the size of the spores.

If they are bigger than the gaps in the thread of the bandanna, the bandanna will stop them and you will be safe.

If they are smaller, the bandanna will not stop them and the infection will spread.

Comment: Conceivably the effect of a bandana could be improved through various relatively simple methods. Maybe it needs to be soaked in water before use. And so re-soaked for dramatic purpose at intervals. Maybe it has to be soaked in alcohol or gas so that the dramatic characters are fumed up all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It's common knowledge that in case you get trapped in a place with a lot of smoke, wet clothes can be used as a filter for proper breathing and avoid intoxication. I would argue that a wet bandana can be used as a filter for zombie spores as they will probably be bigger than smoke particles.

Comment: Wet clothes filter ashes and dust, which are abundant in a fire and during volcanic eruptions. They do not stop anything else.